# How to access one windows content from a second window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0, timer

I need to make an application which has two windows:

**Window 1**
Contains 6 countdown timers.

**Window 2**
Here will the settings og the individual timers be set.

What will be the best solution for this functionality? I will be using c# wpf and .Net 4.0

Comment: what did you try? it should be trivial what is stopping you?

Comment: Should be trivial to just have two forms and instantiate them both. You can reference the components on each form directly (unless you're using multiple threads), as long as they're public.

Comment: @Polynomial never suggest to access UI controls of one form from another one. This is not robust and suggested approach, properties and OO approahc should be used instead. If you expose the Name TextBox instead of simply the Name property, this will create a dependency and code will no longer work same way or need too many changes if the TextBox is replaced with a Label, just as simple example...

Comment: I am using the DispatcherTimer allong with some Timespans and DateTimes.

Comment: "You can reference the components on each form directly". How is that done?

Comment: @DavidePiras - For a small application it shouldn't be too much of a problem, but I do see your point. FireFly3000 - you should take Davide's advice and make a property that wraps the control you want to access (e.g. `public TextBox MyTextBox { get { return this.myTextBox; } set { this.myTextBox = value; } }`) or use a method to expose specific functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MVVM**

**1.** CountDownView
  Represents a single timer View, simple TextBlock bound to a `CurrentValue` property or something more nice/complex instead of TextBlock

**2.** CountDownViewModel
  Represents a single timer itself, expose property `int CurrentValue` displayed as countdown number on the View. To implement countdown you can use [Sytem.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) and in [Elapsed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) handler just decrement CurrentValue property value

**3.** TimersView - for first window with 6 timers

- ItemsCountrol / ListView,
- ItemTemplate - CountDownView
- ItemsSource - bound to a `Timers` property of `TimersViewModel`, basically TimersViewModel shoudl be set to DataContext of the TimersView so you woudl eb able to specify following binding: (and each item will be bound to single Timer)

  `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Timers}" ... />`

**4.** TimersViewModel - expose `IEnumerable<CountDownViewModel> Timers` property

**5.** SettingsView - Settings panel

PS: INotifyPropertyChanged for all VM properties exposed to Views

**Homework for you**:

1. Understand MVVM principles, WPF Bindings and Commands, this would be helpful for you along all your career
2. Implement relation between TimersViewModel and SettingsViewModel yourself

Comment: @FireFly3000 : it would be great! Also I would suggest rename your question to be self descriptive and not such generalized

Comment: Can I get you to describe step 2 and 3 a little bit more?

Comment: How will I set the bindings for step 3?